# html body ondblclick get clicked element

Tags: javascript, html

so in my html i have this portion:

```
<body ondblclick="myfunc();">
<div id="id1">dasd</div>
<div id="id2">dasda</div>
</body>
```

and in javascript the function is :

```
function myfunc() {
    do stuff here...
}
```

i want to know inside myfunc() on which element of the html body the doubleclick was made, because i don't want to triger myfunc() on every doubleclicked element

so how can i detect the id of the element doubleclicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<body ondblclick="myfunc(event);">

function myfunc(e) {
    // e.target -> element that was clicked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your HTML as

```
<body ondblclick="myfunc(event);">
```

and make myfunc as:

```
function myfunc(event) {
     alert(event.target.id); //here you can get element id that is double clicked
     event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define different events with use of on or bind suppose..

```
$("#id").on("doubleClick",function () {} );
```

so it will know that its double click event..

or for javascript you can use like this

```
<body ondblclick="myfunc(event);">

function myfunc(event) {
    do something..

}
```

Comment: The `live()` method is no longer supported. The `on()` method should be used instead.

Comment: who said live() method doesnt support? if ur using jquery then its the best thing to use for future events..

Comment: The jQuery documentation did. See: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Comment: No problem. You should probably update your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>ondblclick event example</title>
<script> 
    function initElement() {
        var body = document.getElementById("bdy");
        body.ondblclick = showAlert;
    }

    function showAlert(e){
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
    window.onload = initElement;
</script>
</head>
<body id="bdy">
<div id="id1">dasd</div>
<div id="id2">dasda</div>
</body>
</html>
```