# How to pass click location to a function as parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to include the element on which i click on to my `ondbclick` event as a parameter to my function `addElement` in order to pass the classes of the element to the new element i am creating with my function.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="A 1">First</div>
  <div class="B 2">Second</div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li id="list1"></li>
  <li id="list2"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
document.body.ondblclick = addElement; //include clicked element as parameter?

function addElement () { 
  var el = document.createElement("li"); 
  var content = document.createTextNode("Hi there"); 
  el.appendChild(content);

  var liID = document.getElementById("list1"); 
  liID.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', el);
}
```

Comment: An event is already passed to your `addElement` function. You just need to use it, by replacing `()` with `(e)`, and then in you function you can access `e.target`, for example

Comment: duplicate.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852178/html-body-ondblclick-get-clicked-element